# C# SQL query exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, ado.net

I'm using C# in .NET 2.0 and I'm trying to access and manipulate a database. I can read as many times from the DB as I want and everything works, but as soon as I try to insert an item I get the following error message:

```
ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
```

I've tried to look this up, but the fixes I was able to find either didn't work or weren't applicable.

I have the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Col1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Col2]='" + val2 + "'", conn);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    if (dataSet.Tables.Count == 0 || dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 1)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES ('" + val1 + "', '" + val2 + "')", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Note: I'm sure I have permissions set up properly, since Visual Studio can insert with the same SQLConnectionString. Also, I am still fairly new to databases, so if I'm doing anything blantently wrong, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't appear to be opening the connection to perform your update *(the exception tells you this)*.

Try this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES ('" + val1 + "', '" + val2 + "')", conn);
            conn.Open();    
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

You can get more details and working example on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2728ad.aspx

Comment: For some reason I assumed that the "using" command handles both open and close, instead of just close. This works, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The `.Fill()` opens the connection if it was not open and then closes it after it's done (only if it did open it itself). That's why that Fill did work. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d.aspx).

But the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't do that, so you need to manually open the connection, with a

```
conn.Open();
```

either just before the ExecNonQuery or before the Fill.

As you are using a "using block", you don't need to explicitly Close() the connection, but that would not be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);` it will automatically open and close connection.
So you need to reopen connection before using insert statement, or replace `DataAdapter` with `SqlCommand` and keep connection opened until you execute *insert* statement.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't open the connection.

This page shows you how to open a SqlConnection with the using statement.

[Your Friend the C# Using Statement](http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/using.aspx)

Comment: Specifically, you need to use conn.Open() just after the using statement.

Comment: Yes, indeed. For a moment I thought that using the using keyword the connection would be opened automagically, but that's not the case. You still have to call conn.Open().

Answer (score 0):

Call conn.Open() before calling cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 0):

You have to open connection, before executing command

```
 conn.Open()  
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES ('" + val1 + "', '" + val2 + "')", conn);  
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call con.open before you call  con.ExecuteNonQuery and con.Close after it. Dataadapter.fill is doing it for you behind the scenes in the earlier code.

Answer (score 0):

Check conn.IsOpen property before using cmd. And SqlCommand is disposable object too, its better practice to enclose it into "using" block.

Answer (score 0):

No-one above is checking to make sure the connection opened.
I use this in my production code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Col1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Col2]='" + val2 + "'", conn);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        if (dataSet.Tables.Count == 0 || dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 1)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES ('" + val1 + "', '" + val2 + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```